# Drupal Accented character causing error in db_insert

Tags: php, drupal, character-encoding, drupal-7

When trying this insert query:

```
//insert into database
$contact_id = db_insert('contact')
    ->fields(array(
        'date_created' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'date_updated' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        'list_id' => $form_state['values']['list_id'],
        'first_name' => $fn,
        'last_name' => $ln,
        'gender' => $g,
        'email' => $ea,
        'company_name' => $cn,
        'is_active' => 1,
    ))
    ->execute();
```

Everything works fine, all the data is loading fine, but when the company name gets an accent, then it causes an error "The website encountered an unexpected error." and the logs just say 'error' on that particular line. Removing the row with the accent solves the problem, but I need to be able to add that accent. If I make the database connection outside of the Drupal way (just mysql_query("INSERT INTO...")) it works fine.

The company name is like: Johns Industriële Company

Database is utf8, table and fields utf8

Hope someone can shed some light on this mystery!

Comment: What is the encoding of `$cn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be an encoding issue in the input. If `$cn ="Johns Industriële Company";` is stored in for example [ISO-8859-1](http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), the sequence `ële` (which in that case should be the byte sequence `eb 6c 66`) will represent an invalid [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) sequence that the database should reject.

Try examining the encoding and bytes of the submitted data.

Comment: Sounds like a good start, how can I check the encoding of a variable?

Comment: Also, would applying utf8_encode() be wise, or am I opening myself up to other problems then?

Comment: The browser should submit the form in the same encoding as the web page containing the form, what is your encoding there? If it is ISO-8859-1 and you intend to keep it that way, then it is a sensible move to apply `utf8_encode()`.

Comment: Drupal sets the meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and using mb_detect_encoding($cn) returns "UTF-8"

Comment: Hmmm but with a more strict check: (mb_detect_encoding($cn, 'UTF-8', true)===false ? 'False':'True') returns "False"

Comment: Okay so it turns out this solves the problem: $cn=(mb_detect_encoding($cn, 'UTF-8', true)===false ? utf8_encode($cn):$cn);    horrible drupal....

Answer (score 2):

Table and field format should be in UTF-8 format.

```
db_insert('table_name')
          ->fields(array(
             'column_name' => utf8_encode('insert_value'),
           ))->execute();
    }
```

insert_value like "Clément".
utf8_encode() function will help you insert the ascent characters.